# Qt progressBar getting Unhandled exception how detect when parent widget is done loading

Tags: c++, qt

im using Qt QProgressBar and place it in the statusBar on my main window 
Like this in the constructor :

```
pb = new QProgressBar(statusBar());
pb->setTextVisible(false);
pb->hide();
statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(pb);
```

then im running procsses (web page loadding in this case ) 
and trying to show the progress with :

```
connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(loadProgress(int)), SLOT(setProgress (int)));
void myMainWindow:: setProgress(int progress)
{
pb->show();
pb->setRange(0,100);
pb->setValue(progress);
}
```

But im getting Unhandled  exception when it comes to pb->show()
I guess it has to do something with loading the parent main windows and then the progress bar 
I was reading about the QAbstractEventDispatcher and processEvents but not understood how to implement it .

i did small test and put the pb->show() function call in button click signal/slut 
that means im triggering the pb->show() after the web page and the mainwindows fully loaded and its working fine without the exception. that make me belive there is problem
with the event processing.

here is the class :

```
class MainWindowMainWindowContainer : public QMainWindow 
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MainWindowContainer(QWidget *parent = 0);

 public slots:

    void adjustLocation();
    void changeLocation();
    void adjustTitle();
    void setProgress(int p);
    void finishLoading(bool);
    void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);


private:
    Ui::OnLineBack_mainWindow ui;    
    int progress;

    void createWebViewActions();
    QProgressBar *pb;
    void setprogressBar(int progress,bool show);

 };

MainWindowContainer::MainWindowContainer(QWidget* parent) : 
    QMainWindow(parent),

{
 ui.setupUi(this);
 progress = 0;


createWebViewActions();
ui.webView->load(QUrl("www.cnnnn.com"));
ui.webView->show();

pb = new QProgressBar(statusBar());
pb->setTextVisible(false);
pb->hide();
statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(pb);
}
 void MainWindowContainer::createWebViewActions()
{
    connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(adjustLocation()));
    connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(titleChanged(QString)), SLOT(adjustTitle()));
    connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(loadProgress(int)), SLOT(setProgress(int)));
    connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)), SLOT(finishLoading(bool)));
    connect(ui.webView, SIGNAL(linkClicked(const QUrl&)),this, SLOT(linkClicked(const QUrl&)));

}
void MainWindowContainer::setProgress(int p)
{
    progress = p;
    adjustTitle();
}
 void MainWindowContainer::adjustTitle()
{
    qApp->processEvents(); 

    pb->show();
    if (progress <= 0 || progress >= 100)
    {
        QString titl =  ui.webView->title();
        statusBar()->showMessage(titl);
        setprogressBar(-1,false);

    }
    else
    {

        statusBar()->showMessage(QString("%1 (%2%)").arg(ui.webView->title()).arg(progress));
        setprogressBar(progress,true);
    }
}

 void MainWindowContainer::finishLoading(bool)
{   
    progress = 100;
    adjustTitle();

}
 void MainWindowContainer::setprogressBar(int progress,bool show)
{
     if(show)
    {
        pb->show();
        pb->setRange(0,100);
        pb->setValue(progress);
    }
    else
    {
        pb->hide();
    } 
}
```

Comment: I gues we need more code to determine whats wrong. If you created your widget, calling ->show() is just fine. You don't have to "wait for loading" widget. Your doing something else wrong.

Comment: what code do you need more ?  im calling the main window app with :
MainWindowContainer mainWindowContainer;
mainWindowContainer.show();

Comment: Where is pb defined? Where is the connect called?

Comment: The pb defined in the MainWindow.h file and set to object in the MainWindow constructor . the connect called also in the  MainWindow constructor

Comment: Show whole constructor body and class declaration

Comment: updated my original post with the class decleration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `createWebViewActions()` function you connect the signals to their respective slots. (One small remark, the connect for the `titleChanged(QString)` signal and `adjustTitle()` slot fails because they have different signatures)

Among others you are connecting the signal `loadProgress(int)` to slot `setProgress(int)`. In this slot you call `adjustTitle()` where the instruction pb->show() is being executed.

Notice that you are calling the `createWebViewActions()` function before the call to QProgressBar constructor

```
(...)
createWebViewActions();  <------ here you establish the signal->slot connections
ui.webView->load(QUrl("www.cnnnn.com"));
ui.webView->show();

pb = new QProgressBar(statusBar()); <------ here you call the QProgressBar constructor
pb->setTextVisible(false);
pb->hide();
statusBar()->addPermanentWidget(pb);
(...)
```

I think that maybe this slot `(setProgress())` is being called before the QProgressBar is constructed which triggers the Unhandled exception you are getting.

You could try and move the call to the QProgressBar constructor so that it is created before the slots connection.